# How to disable Scroll left/right on UIPageViewController?

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have been researching this all day, there are many posts about this but I haven't managed to find any that are helpfull for me!

I have a UIPageViewController which displays two views(It is not a root view).

Basically when I add a function from one of those views inside the UIPageViewController I would like to be able to disable the scrolling...?

Is that possible in any way?!

Many thanks in advance to anyone that help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution!

In your page view controller, add following

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourpageviewcontroller.enableSwipe(_:)), name:"enableSwipe", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourpageviewcontroller.disableSwipe(_:)), name:"disableSwipe", object: nil)

    }
    func disableSwipe(notification: NSNotification){
        self.dataSource = nil
    }

func enableSwipe(notification: NSNotification){
    self.dataSource = self
}
```

In your child view controller, you can just post notification by following.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("enableSwipe", object: nil)
```

OR

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("disableSwipe", object: nil)
```